# Using plus symbol + at the beginning of a formula

Tags: google-sheets

In the past days I was looking for a solution and found this formula (not related with the problem I had):

```
=+SORT(A:A;A:A="ab c";;A:A;1)
```

I was curious and I tested this formula following the instruction of the guy who posted it in another forum witch where I can't remember right now. 
The symbol `+` made the `SORT` function return the first cell alone that matches the criteria.

But I want to know more about this kind of customization of formulas using `+` and if is possible to use other operators. Is it documented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent to [unary plus](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093608?hl=en&ref_topic=3105518), also available as `UPLUS` in Google Sheets. It's also equivalent to writing `=0 + foo`

The only effect of this computation is that if `foo` is an array, you get the first element of the array since `+` is not within an `arrayformula`. This is not a special feature of + itself: any non-array operation, when given an array as an argument, uses only the first element of the array. But unary plus is convenient in that it has no other effect on the entry.

Also relevant is the command `array_constrain(array, num_rows, num_columns)` which selects a subarray of given size. But writing `=+array` is certainly easier than `=array_constrain(array, 1, 1)`